# Concatenation of AWK array variables - unexpected behaviour

Tags: string, awk, concatenation

Input file

```
steve,apples
steve,oranges
john,pears
john,oranges
mary,bananas
steve,plums
mary,nactarines
```

I want to get output like this:

```
steve:apples,oranges,plums
john:pears,oranges
mary:bananas,nectarines
```

Here is the one liner I have been trying to get to work:

```
awk -F, '{if(a[$1])a[$1]=a[$1]","$2; else a[$1]=$2;}END{for (i in a)print i ":" a[i];}' OFS=, inputfile
```

The output it gives is

```
,orangesrs
,plumsesples
,nactariness
```

It would appear that the string concatenation `a[$1]=a[$1]","$2` is resulting in the original value of the array element to be overwritten to some degree. How can I carry out this concatenation correctly?

Incidentally, I get the same results on Centos, and Mac OSX.

Comment: I tested your awk line, it gave desired output here.

Comment: That's strange. The file I had was one given to me by a customer, thart I then modified/simplified to show this proof of concept. I just  recreated the file from scratch, and hey presto, it works... so I wonder why that original file didn't work!

Comment: Arrrghhh! The file was from a Windows machine - it was the extra CR that was causing stuff to get overwritten. Lesson learnt!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1]FS$2:$2)} END {for (i in a) print i":"a[i]}' file
mary:bananas,nactarines
john:pears,oranges
steve:apples,oranges,plums
```

PS After posted it, I see that this is the same as Kent posted, but no info on why deleted.

Comment: @EdMorton I do forgetting :)