# Group matching lines in a text file together

Tags: regex, linux, perl, grep

I have an input file:

```
XYZ_001
XYZ_005
XYZ_010
ABC_001
ABC_010
```

I would like to groups these lines into:

```
XYZ,XYZ_001,XYZ_005,XYZ_010
ABC,ABC_001,ABC_010
```

I have tried sorting the files and filtering out the last four characters, but I don't know how to group them together. Basically, I need to group the lines that match a regular expression together. My input file is sorted.

My file is huge. I cannot slurp the entire file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenation of AWK array variables - unexpected behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433376/concatenation-of-awk-array-variables-unexpected-behaviour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^([^_]+_).*\K\n(?=\1)/,/mg; s/^([^_]*)\K/,$1/mg;' file
```

If slurping is not an option, then this longer form logic would work:

```
perl -ne '
      chomp;
      ($h) = /([^_]*)/;
      if ($l ne $h) {print "\n" if defined $l; $l = $h; print "$l"}
      print ",$_";
    }{
      print "\n"
    ' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-0777`: Slurp the entire file
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `s/^([^_]+_).*\K\n(?=\1)/,/mg`: Group related adjacent lines:  `XYZ_001,XYZ_005,XYZ_010`
- `s/^([^_]*)\K/,$1/mg`: Add group prefix: `XYZ,XYZ_001,XYZ_005,XYZ_010`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My file is huge. I cannot slurp the entire file.

Comment: @Ari Okay.  Then I propose a second option if you can't slurp.

Comment: @Ari Please note, that every other solution currently proposed also loads the entire file into memory, except they use 5 times the memory because the data is loaded into a hash.  My first option will use much less memory if that's actually a concern, but my optional second version actually streams the file to avoid any memory load at all.

Comment: @Miller True but the second solution expects the file to be ordered. Not sure if that is an issue since OP has accepted this solution.

Comment: @jaypal From the question: "*My input file is sorted.*"  But aye, neither of my solutions would work if that wasn't the case.

Comment: @Miller Aah crap! I missed reading that. Sorry about that. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner to do it:

```
perl -ne 'chomp;if (/^([a-zA-Z]+)_/) { $hash{$1} .= ",$_"; } } END { for (keys %hash ) { print $_ . $hash{$_} . "\n" } ' input.txt
```

input.txt:

```
XYZ_001
XYZ_005
XYZ_010
ABC_001
ABC_010
```

output:

```
ABC,ABC_001,ABC_010
XYZ,XYZ_001,XYZ_005,XYZ_010
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this sort of thing, which stores your ids and values in a hash of arrays and then iterates through them and prints:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';

my %data;
my (@group, @n);
while (<$in>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split(/_/);
    push @group, $split[0];
    push @n, $split[1];
}

push @{$data{$group[$_]} }, [ $n[$_] ] for 0 .. $#group;


for my $group (reverse sort keys %data){
    for my $vals (@ {$data{$group} }) {
        my ($number) = @$vals; 
        print "$group\_$number,";
        }
        print "\n";
}
```

---

```
XYZ_001,XYZ_005,XYZ_010,
ABC_001,ABC_010,
```

Answer (score 0):

perl onliner:

```
perl  -F"_" -ane 'chomp;$s{$F[0]}.=",$_";END{ for $i (keys %s){print $i.$s{$i}."\n";} }' FILE
```

i use uniq hash

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this using `awk`

```
awk -F_ '{a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1]","$0:$0)} END {for (i in a) print i","a[i]}' file
ABC,ABC_001,ABC_010
XYZ,XYZ_001,XYZ_005,XYZ_010
```